# Arduino control peristaltic pump

Tags: potentiometer, digital-potentiometer

I'm working with a colleague to digitally control an old peristaltic pump using a digital potentiometer. The existing pump controller has a mechanical potentiometer and we are trying to replace it with an [MCP4131-103](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General%20IC/22060b.pdf).

**Can anyone lend some insight on the types of questions we should be asking before doing a direct replacement?** We have already burned a couple and I suspect we are wiring it incorrectly or using an under-rated IC. One measurement we already have is that the voltage across the A-B of the mechanical pot during operation is about 10V (from ground, I think I measured -40V on A and -50V on B, if that matters). **Is that too much for this IC? Can anyone provide some pointers on how to proceed? Is there a better way to replace a mechanical pot than with a digital pot to allow for programmatic control?**

Thanks in advance for the help provided. If I need to provide clearer details, please tell me some measurements/observations I can make about the current setup.

Answer (score 1):

Whoa, no wonder you're burning these:

| Absolute Maximum Ratings |  |
| --- | --- |
| Voltage on V<sub>DD</sub> with respect to V<sub>SS</sub> | -0.6V to +7.0V |
| Voltage on /CS, SCK, SDI, SDI/SDO, and /SHDN with respect to V<sub>SS</sub> | -0.6V to 12.5V |
| Voltage on all other pins (PxA, PxW, PxB, and SDO) with respect to V<sub>SS</sub> | -0.3V to V<sub>DD</sub>+0.3V |

Essentially, you're feeding -40 and -50 volts to the pins PxA, PxW and PxB. Their *absolute limit* is rated at -0.3, up to VDD+0.3 volts. VDD can be up to 7 volts without damage, but the typical operating voltage is 5 volts.

There are a number digital potentiometers that can handle 10 volts, but you must make sure that you *float* them, if the pins you need to use really are at a potential of -40 or -50 volts. This is not necessarily easy to do.

Another alternative are motorized potentiometers.

You may get more solutions if you try to post the current schematic, maybe there's a way to bypass the potentiometer completely.

Comment: "try to post the current schematic, maybe there's a way to bypass the potentiometer completely." - Full ack!

Comment: I hope to verify that those pins are indeed -40V/-50V (I may have gotten a bad reading). I'll try to post more/better details if I can. I really appreciate the feedback already. I thought that was probably the case, but needed confirmation.